# iOutValue of Dictionary Class in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Issue : Difference in behavior of dictionary class in C# .NET

Description : In the code snippet given below, In .NET 3.5 version, we got -1 in iOutValue variable if the value doesn't exist in Dictionary. But with .NET 4.5, we are getting 0 in iOutValue variable if the value doesn't exist in the Dictionary.

Code Snippet:

```
Dictionary<Int32, Int32> dicobj = new Dictionary<Int32, Int32>;
Int32 iOutValue = -1; 
dicobj.TryGetValue(0, out iOutValue);
Console.WriteLine("Out Value : " + iOutValue);
```

The same code snippet executed using the two different versions of .Net framework. the values in iOutValue is different in the two versions. How can that be possible?

Comment: No, you would never have observed `iOutValue` as -1. `Dictionary<,>.TryGetValue` has *always* set the out parameter to the default value of `TValue` if the key isn't present. It's hard to say why you believe that wasn't the case in .NET 3.5, but I'm absolutely convinced you're mistaken.

Comment: It's also documented: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.90).aspx _"otherwise, the default value for the type of the value parameter"_ The default value of any numeric type is 0.

Comment: See also: [out parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) -- "the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns." -- it *must not* just "leave it be whatever it was before". It is *required* to assign "something". In this case: `default(int)`.

Comment: thanks , this information was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Double check the code for both versions.

It doesn't matter what the object's value was prior to `TryGetValue` being called. It's either `TValue`, or the default value for `TValue`. `Int` becomes 0, objects become null, etc etc.

Perhaps there really was a key 0 that had a value of -1?